# Should I choose low fat milk or full fat milk?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I am a healthy man with normal weight so I'm not concerned with weight loss.  For me milk is an important part of my diet. I've read recent studies saying that low fat products are not always good. I was searching online if I should use low fat milk or full fat. But I found contradicting posts.

For example, [this post](http://www.helpguide.org/articles/healthy-eating/choosing-healthy-fats.htm) claims that full fat milk should be replaced with low fat option. On the other hand [this post](http://www.womansday.com/health-fitness/nutrition/advice/g894/unhealthy-fat-free-foods/?slide=4) claims otherwise. Whom to trust? Is there any scientific study which can give a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

From "[Consumption of Dairy Products in Relation to Changes in Anthropometric Variables in Adult Populations: A Systematic Review and Meta-Analysis of Cohort Studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4911011/)" (2016):

> The current state of knowledge regarding the association of dairy products and weight gain, overweight, and obesity is based on studies reporting **contradicting and inconclusive results**.

I recommend reading above review and reading through its bibliography.

Answer (score -1):

My professor at university, class of nutrition, said he would prefer full fat milk because is much richer in liposoluble vitamins. The difference of calories is not that big if the rest of the diet is balanced.

Comment: And it is tastier! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Attilio for the answer. Recommendation from the professor should be authentic.

Comment: Though professors can usually be trusted, we need better sources to back up answers here than just word of mouth. Could you please add a better reference?